# Is it possible to adjust simple membership to accept logins by finger print scanners in MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership, fingerprint

I'm developing a critical management app using MVC 4. I want to enforce managers and admins to login to the app only by their finger prints. Is it possible? If so, What is a starting point for me?

tanx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should install the driver of that device to be able to perform this kind of login. then u can handle them through the simple membership

Answer (score 1):

What is your fingerprint device? it should have a SDK, you should find it's SDK and try to integrate your application with that.